# Create a Parent div for multiple child divs - Jquery

Tags: jquery

My code goes like this,

```
<div class="sExample">
    <div class="child1 one">...</div>
    <div class="child2 one">...</div>

    <table>...</table>
    <div class="child3">...</div>
</div>
```

I want to include a parent div only for the `.child1` and `.child2` targeting class `.one`. I tried the jQuery `.wrap` method, but its adding parent div for each items.

Please help me do this.

Comment: What code do you have right now that "isn't working"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want the result to look like this:

```
<div class="sExample">
    <div>
        <div class="child1 one">...</div>
        <div class="child2 one">...</div>
    </div>

    <table>...</table>
    <div class="child3">...</div>
</div>
```

Use `wrapAll()` instead of `wrap()`:

```
$('.one').wrapAll('<div>');
```

Comment: Thank you Jason. This is so cool and understood about wrapALL(). +1

Answer (score 1):

Use this for wrap **each** element in it own container:

```
$('.one').wrap('<div></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use appendTo() to move the element. Also, if possible, try using an id for the parent div .sExample it would be easier to manipulate in code.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.child1 .one')[0].appendTo(document.getElementsByClassName('.sExample')[0])
```

You would probably have to iterate over your classes if you have multiple classes with the same name. Once again, I suggest moving to ids if you can.